# How to get battery temperature from Battery Manager Class in android?

Tags: java, android

This is my BattreyInfo.java file. I am trying to extract the battery temperature and display it on my screen. The Eclipse says the `BroadcastReciever` cannot be resolved to a type. I dont understand. I have properly imported the package. It also does not recognize the `onRecieve` function. Do I have to make another class or something for `BroadcastReciever`?

```
package com.example.batterywidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color; 
import android.view.View;


public class BatteryInfo extends Activity {

private TextView BatTemp;
BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReciever = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onRecieve(Context arg0, Intent intent){
        int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
        BatTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp) + "%");

    }
};

    //called when the activity is first created
    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle binfo){
     super.onCreate(binfo);
     setContentView(R.layout.batteryinfo);
     BatTemp = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.battery_temp);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver, filter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BroadcastReceiver is an abstract class. This means that you cannot make an instance of it. You have to create your own class and extend BroadcastReceiver.

I think you can copy all of your existing code into your new class.

You seem to have 3 Broadcasters.
The first one shoudl look like this:

```
public class BatInfoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
 @Override
    public void onRecieve(Context arg0, Intent intent){
        int temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
        BatTemp.setText(String.valueOf(temp) + "%");

    }
}
```

Now its possible to make an instance of this class:

```
BatInforeceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BatInfoReceiver();
```

And then you do the same with your other two BroadcastReceivers.

Comment: Should i extend the BatteryInfo with BroadcastReciever instead of Activity ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I wish I had enough reputation to vote this up !

Comment: God luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,
                        -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batteryLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

Comment: the issue is that my eclipse says that BroadcastReciever cannot be resolved to a type ? How is that ? I have properly imported the package. Do I need to make a BroadcastReciever Class in a separate java file ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I used to get the temperature

```
batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            int level = -1;
            int scale = -1;
            int temperature = -1;
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                temperature = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);

                int health = intent.getIntExtra("health",BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN);
                String strHealth;
                if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD){
                    strHealth = "Good";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT){
                    strHealth = "Over Heat";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD){
                    strHealth = "Dead";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE){
                    strHealth = "Over Voltage";
                } else if (health == BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE){
                    strHealth = "Unspecified Failure";
                } else{
                    strHealth = "Unknown";
                }


                batteryStatusTextView.setText(" Temperature: "+temperature/10+"C" + " " + strHealth);

            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Yes. But how did you write BroadcatReciever. My eclipse says that it cannot be resolved to a tyPE. I know its an abstract class but how shud i correct it. Should i extend the BatteryInfo with BroadcastReciever instead of Activity ?

Comment: the batteryReceiver is declared like: public BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver; That's it. My class is just an activty nothing else, it does not implement anything refered to the BroadcastReceiver. I just import the 
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; and the code above is implemented in onCreate. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

```
BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    int scale = -1;
    int level = -1;
    int voltage = -1;
    int temp = -1;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
        voltage = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
        Log.e("BatteryManager", "level is "+level+"/"+scale+", temp is "+temp+", voltage is "+voltage);
    }
};
```